# JQuery custom validation error

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am facing the following issue with the JQuery validator:
I have a form where I am using the default validation rules provided and everything works fine.
Howoever, as soon as I add a custom validation, the following error is thrown:

1. in Chrome: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addMethod' of undefined
2. in IE8: 'validator' is null or not an object
3. FireFox: no error message, but the JQuery default validation logic breaks;

The piece of code which is causing the error to occur is this (it sits inside the ready function):

```
$().validator.addMethod("defaultInvalid", 
   function(value, element) {   
    alert("validate");
   }
 );
```

As you see I have commented most of the code of the callback function in order to eliminate any other error.
if I comment it, everything goes back to normal.
However, I would like to use this customized rule on a text box taht must have the default value of "First name" and on submit it should not allow the user to send "First name" as value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at this, validator won't be found as it's looking inside `$()`. You need to just use `$.validator.addMeth....` which goes into the default jquery object.

Like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("defaultInvalid", 
   function(value, element) {   
    alert("validate");
});
```

**or** whatever you use to access Jquery object

```
JQuery.validator.addMethod("defaultInvalid", 
   function(value, element) {   
    alert("validate");
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, to be honest I was not aware of that. Many examples that I have seen online contain this error.

Comment: No problem, I have been working with this plugin for the past few days so it's fresh in my head ;-)

Comment: @Stokedout, I have the right syntax but still get error. firefox says: `$.validator` is undefined and chrome says the same as this question. any ideas y?

Comment: Check the order in which javascript files are loaded. You want your custom method to be last once Jquery, then Jquery validate has loaded